# How to have two check box events running at the same time in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create a form in Visual Basic that allows people to write reviews on vintage records. As it is showing the end result, I must be able to let the user make the text become bolder, italic, underlined, etc. I wish to do this by using checkboxes, but I'm not sure what code do I write if I were to have two checkbox events running at the same time.

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: To set font style of which control(s).? Do you have any code, screenshot maybe?

Answer (score 3):

There won't be *"two checkbox events running at the same time"*.  What you actually mean is two `CheckBoxes` checked at the same time.  It's fairly simple because the `Style` property of the `Font` applied to your `TextBox` is type `FontStyle`, which supports composite values.  In the `CheckedChanged` event of the `CheckBox` for Bold, you would do this sort of thing:

```
If CheckBox1.Checked Then
    'Apply the Bold style.
    TextBox1.Font = New Font(TextBox1.Font, TextBox1.Font.Style Or FontStyle.Bold)
Else
    'Remove the Bold style.
    TextBox1.Font = New Font(TextBox1.Font, TextBox1.Font.Style And Not FontStyle.Bold)
End If
```

You simply replace `Bold` with the appropriate field in the other event handlers.

It may seem slightly counter-intuitive to use `Or` in that situation but it's important to understand that this is a bitwise operation.  Bitwise operations are essentially Boolean operations on each pair of bits in the operands, where 1 represent `True` and 0 represents `False`.  It's easy to see what's happening when you use binary representations.

`Enums` like `FontStyle` are friendly representations of numbers.  The `Bold`, `Italic` and `Underline` fields have values of 1, 2 and 4 respectively, which are 001, 010 and 100 in binary.  As you can see, each field has one and only one bit set in its binary representation.  Bitwise operations are useful because they can set or reset a single bit in a combined value.  For instance, if you have no styles set and you want to apply the `Bold` style you get this:

```
000
001
---OR
001
```

The result will have a particular bit set if that bit is set in the first operand OR the second, hence the bitwise `Or` operator.  If you then wanted to set the `Underline` style too:

```
001
100
---OR
101
```

So the combination of `Bold` and `Underline` is 101 in binary, which is 5 in decimal.  If you then wanted remove the `Bold` style, you would first `Not` the `Bold` style, which means toggling each and every bit:

```
001
---NOT
110
```

and you would then `And` that result with the existing combined style:

```
101
110
---AND
100
```

The bitwise `And` operator will set a bit in the result if that not is set in the first operand AND the second operand.  In this case, the only bit that is set in both operands is the first, so it is the only bit set in the result.  That means that the result is 100 in binary, which is 4 in decimal and equal to the `Underline` style, which is exactly what we would expect.

EDIT:

Here is a set of extension methods that makes working with controls and font styles easier:

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module ControlExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Sub AddFontStyle(source As Control, style As FontStyle)
        source.Font = New Font(source.Font, source.Font.Style Or style)
    End Sub

    <Extension>
    Public Sub RemoveFontStyle(source As Control, style As FontStyle)
        source.Font = New Font(source.Font, source.Font.Style And Not style)
    End Sub

    <Extension>
    Public Sub ToggleFontStyle(source As Control, style As FontStyle)
        source.Font = New Font(source.Font, source.Font.Style Xor style)
    End Sub

    <Extension>
    Public Function ContainsFontStyle(source As Control, style As FontStyle) As Boolean
        Return (source.Font.Style And style) = style
    End Function

End Module
```

Here is some sample usage:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.AddFontStyle(FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TextBox1.RemoveFontStyle(FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    TextBox1.ToggleFontStyle(FontStyle.Bold)
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    MessageBox.Show(TextBox1.ContainsFontStyle(FontStyle.Bold).ToString())
End Sub
```

As you can see, calling the extensions as instance methods is simpler than writing out the full bitwise expression each time.

Comment: Oh I see, I did not know this at first. Does this only occur in visual basic or other programming languages as well?

Comment: @Sam it is pretty ubiquitous among all programming languages. Look up [Bitwise Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: [FontStyle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.fontstyle?view=netframework-4.8) is a special kind of Enum with the [Flags attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8) which means it behaves as stated in this answer. Each possible value of the enum is a power of 2: {1, 2, 4, 8}: {Bold, Italic, Underline, Strikeout} (0 for Regular is the absence of any additional formatting). Powers of 2 can be combined to create any non-negative integer. For FontStyle, values from 0 to 15 (2^4-1) represent all possible combinations.

Comment: @djv, it's not the `Flags` attribute that makes `FontStyle` and other `Enums` behave this way but rather that `Enums` that behave this way should have the `Flags` attribute applied.  The one and only thing that `Flags` does is make the `ToString` method output the name of each field from a combined value rather than the numeric value.  It's purely the numerical values that make an `Enum` able to be combined usefully.  You may have known this already but didn't express it clearly.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `FontStyle` breaks the rule of using plural names for `Enums` that can be combined and singular names for those that can't, unless you consider "style" to be both singular and plural in this context.

Comment: @jmcilhinney maybe `it behaves as ...` should have been `the developer intends for it to be used as ...`. The attribute is just a flag itself that it's just signaling that it's used a certain way... As for the naming convention, I wasn't aware of it. Thanks. More info for OP in [Flags' remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks).

Comment: I have added some useful extension methods to the answer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney could you help me out by typing in the code for me to use in my project using bitwise operations? I would like to know an alternative way than calling an extension. I am still not sure of how it works. Thanks a lot.